# Finding dialog in a paragraph with Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, split, nlp

How can I extract dialog, the sentences between quotes, from a paragraph and store the results in an array, using javascript?

```
var myParagraph = '
“Of course I’ll go Kate. You should get back to bed. Would you like some Nyquil or Tylenol?”
“Nyquil, please. Here are the questions and my mini-disc recorder. Just press record here. Make notes, I’ll transcribe it all.”
“I know nothing about him,” I murmur, trying and failing to suppress my rising panic. “The questions will see you through. Go. It’s a long drive. I don’t want you to be late.” “Okay, I’m going. Get back to bed. I made you some soup to heat up later.” I stare at her fondly. Only for you, Kate, would I do this.'
```

How can I split myParagraph to return an array like:

```
paragraphArray = ["Of course I’ll go Kate. You should get back to bed. Would you like some Nyquil or Tylenol?",
"Nyquil, please. Here are the questions and my mini-disc recorder. Just press record here. Make notes, I’ll transcribe it all.",
"I know nothing about him,",
"The questions will see you through. Go. It’s a long drive. I don’t want you to be late.",
"Okay, I’m going. Get back to bed. I made you some soup to heat up later."]
```

Thanks.

Comment: There's got to be a RegExp for this. But first, you need to make sure your source code doesn't have any formatted characters, like the "smart quotes" you are showing (`“”`) and instead use straight quotes (`""`).

Answer (score 1):

```
paragraphArray = myParagraph.slice(1, myParagraph.length-2).split("”“");
```

I think this work.

Answer (score 0):

A regex would be a good choice here. As mentioned in a comment, make sure that the quotes present in the string are regular `"` quotes, or modify the regex to use the left and right quotes instead. So either:

`/"(.*?)"/` For regular quotes, or:

`/“(.*?)”/` For the directional quotes.

Then, the regex `"(.*?)"` just says to capture everything between two quote characters, with a non-greedy search. Finally, add the `g` flag to the regex so that it will get all matches, not just the first.

The string method `.match` accepts a regex and returns an array of matches. The exact format of the array changes depending on if the regex had the `g` flag. Since we do use that flag, it returns an array of each full match (including the enclosing quotes), so you may want to strip the quotes from each result.

Here's a working example:

```js
var myParagraph = `
"Of course I’ll go Kate. You should get back to bed. Would you like some Nyquil or Tylenol?"
"Nyquil, please. Here are the questions and my mini-disc recorder. Just press record here. Make notes, I’ll transcribe it all."
"I know nothing about him," I murmur, trying and failing to suppress my rising panic. "The questions will see you through. Go. It’s a long drive. I don’t want you to be late." "Okay, I’m going. Get back to bed. I made you some soup to heat up later." I stare at her fondly. Only for you, Kate, would I do this.`

const rgx = /"(.*?)"/g;

const dialogue = myParagraph
    .match(rgx) // Match using our regex
    .map(result => result.replace(/"/g, "")) // Remove quotes from each result, remove this line if you want to keep the enclosing quotes

console.log(dialogue)
```

Answer (score 0):

If your paragraph doesn't contain `newline` characters then you can do this.

```js
var myParagraph = ' “Of course I’ll go Kate. You should get back to bed. Would you like some Nyquil or Tylenol?” “Nyquil, please. Here are the questions and my mini-disc recorder. Just press record here. Make notes, I’ll transcribe it all.” “I know nothing about him,” I murmur, trying and failing to suppress my rising panic. “The questions will see you through. Go. It’s a long drive. I don’t want you to be late.” “Okay, I’m going. Get back to bed. I made you some soup to heat up later.” I stare at her fondly. Only for you, Kate, would I do this.';

// captures everything between “ and ” except for newline character
// '?' stands for nongreedy search
const regex = /“[^\n]*?”/g;
const result = [];
let match;

// while there is anything to capture, push it to result
while (match = regex.exec(myParagraph)) {
  result.push(match[0]);
}

console.log(result);
```

Optionally if you want to remove `“` as you do in your question. You can create a capture group and use its content to push it into result instead.

```js
var myParagraph = ' “Of course I’ll go Kate. You should get back to bed. Would you like some Nyquil or Tylenol?” “Nyquil, please. Here are the questions and my mini-disc recorder. Just press record here. Make notes, I’ll transcribe it all.” “I know nothing about him,” I murmur, trying and failing to suppress my rising panic. “The questions will see you through. Go. It’s a long drive. I don’t want you to be late.” “Okay, I’m going. Get back to bed. I made you some soup to heat up later.” I stare at her fondly. Only for you, Kate, would I do this.';

// here `(, )` defines a capture group
const regex = /“([^\n]*?)”/g;
const result = [];
let match;
while (match = regex.exec(myParagraph)) {
  // note the change: 0 => 1
  result.push(match[1]);
}

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Holy moses y'all are quick. Thanks. That worked. Take care.